# Risk of overloading motor controller

Tags: motor, battery

I bought 2 brushed motor controllers from China for my hobby-weight battle robot (http://www.banggood.com/ESC-Brushed-Speed-Controller-For-RC-Car-Truck-Boat-320A-7_2V-16V-p-915276.html).

These are intended for use with my 2 cordless drill 14.4v motors which will be driving the left and right wheel respectively.

I will be using 4S LIPOs which (when fully charged) have a voltage of 16.8V. Can someone put my mind at rest that the .8 volt excess is unlikely to damage the controller (which is rated for 7.2v - 16v)?

Also is the fact that the motor controllers are rated for 320Amp likely to damage my motors?

I am to be honest not very clear on current and how this is drawn from a LIPO battery. For instance would connecting a LIPO directly to my motor result in a massive discharge or does the motor just "take what it needs" in terms of current? Can someone maybe kindly point me to an article which casts some light on the subject or even more kindly explain it to me here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the motor just takes what it needs.
The 320 A rating means it will survive that current if the motor requires it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not exceed the voltage rating of the controller -- it's there for a reason.

If the motor itself is rated for 16.8 VDC (or more) then there is no problem connecting it directly to the battery.

If you have questions about electronics specifically, you should post them on the [stackexchange site for electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).